# SwipeRefreshLayout -- how to detect the drag distance?

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I'm using SwipeRefreshLayout in my layout, and I need to show an animation that adjusts to the distance that has been pulled down.

So far I haven't found any way to detect the actual distance that has been pulled.  The SwipeRefreshListener only detects whether a refresh has occurred.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: stuck on same thing,if you got answer,do let me know.

Comment: looking at the code, it looks doubtful. There is a private variable called mFromPercentage that probably holds the value we are looking for.  Unfortunately, I don't see any way to access it.

Comment: i am also trying,if get something ,then will let you know soon buddy.

Answer (score 1):

To monitor the drag distance, you can simply track the distance beetween the SwiperefreshLayout top and its only direct child top.

The only way I found to observe the distance change was using a PrewDrawListener.

Here's a code snippet:

```
swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
...
final View swipeTarget = swipeRefreshLayout.getChildAt(0);

swipeTarget.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        dragDistance = swipeTarget.getTop() - swipeRefreshLayout.getTop();
        return true;
    }
});
```